# Python Import error while running through apache

Tags: python, apache, cgi

Actually I've included the python script inside CGI script with back-ticks. While i was running the script I have an error like "ImportError: No module named skimage" through apache web server. But when i run via command line it was working properly.

OS: RHEL 6.5

Python: 2.7.8

$PYTHONPATH = /usr/local/bin

**httpd conf (only CGI Part):**

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/cgi-bin>
     Options ExecCGI
     AddHandler cgi-script .py .cgi
     SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note: 1. SELinux is already disabled
      2. Shebang lines was included.

Can anyone help?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to use mod_wgsi https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the library is installed only for you and not for root. Put the library script in the same folder of your main script and try.